# Getting error as 'Unable to load cache item'

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a sprinboot project and no error is shown before execution but when i run the program i am getting the error as unable to load cache item.
This is the console log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:75) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:130) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:317) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:562) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:407) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at spring.context@6.0.11/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:138) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:na]
    at spring.context@6.0.11/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:na]
    at spring.context@6.0.11/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:531) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:na]
    at spring.context@6.0.11/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:na]
    at spring.context@6.0.11/org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:358) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:na]
    at spring.context@6.0.11/org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:150) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:na]
    at spring.context@6.0.11/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:771) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:na]
    at spring.context@6.0.11/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:589) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@3.1.3/org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@3.1.3/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@3.1.3/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@3.1.3/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@3.1.3/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@3.1.3/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:na]
    at login/com.viren.resume.ResumeApplication.main(ResumeApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.viren.resume.ResumeApplication$$SpringCGLIB$$0 (in module login) cannot access class org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (in unnamed module @0x4da4253) because module login does not read unnamed module @0x4da4253
    at login/com.viren.resume.ResumeApplication$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$STATICHOOK1(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at login/com.viren.resume.ResumeApplication$$SpringCGLIB$$0.<clinit>(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:551) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:371) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:575) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.lambda$new$1(AbstractClassGenerator.java:107) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.lambda$createEntry$1(LoadingCache.java:52) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:57) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

I tried making changes in the module-info file but nothing happened

Comment: Welcome, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example